# javadoc: error - java.lang.OutOfMemoryError

Tags: maven-2, maven-3, maven-release-plugin, maven-javadoc-plugin

I'm trying to create a release with maven-release-plugin. The goals I had executed are release:perpare and release:perform.

After maven creates the release and source jar, I get this memory error from javadoc execution.

```
 [INFO] javadoc: error - java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Please increase memory.
 [INFO] For example, on the Sun Classic or HotSpot VMs, add the option -J-Xmx
 [INFO] such as -J-Xmx32m.
```

1. In build section I have this:

   org.apache.maven.plugins
       maven-release-plugin
       2.4.1
       
       @{project.artifactId}-version-@{project.version}
2. I tried to configure javadoc execution on this ways
   a. 
      
          org.apache.maven.plugins
          maven-javadoc-plugin
          2.9
          
           -J-Xmx1024M
          
      
   b.

   org.apache.maven.plugins
     maven-javadoc-plugin
     2.9
     
          1024M

Someone knows what I can do to solve this error?

Thanks!
Juan Pablo Proverbio

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved it with this:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-javadoc-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.2</version>
    <configuration>
        <maxmemory>800m</maxmemory>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

before the  maven-release-plugin definition.